# Случайное перемешивание с random_shuffle();

Tags: g++, c++, ubuntu

Рано мне учителя присвоили... ну да ладно. В общем есть колода карт:

```
deque deck;
```

и описанный класс, с картами(номер, масть и т.п.). В нем есть процедура, загоняющая в deck все карты подряд и потом с использованием

```
random_shuffle(deck, deck.begin(), deck.end());
```

перемешивается, но это псевдослучайные числа, а мне надо случайные. Короче, подскажите, как правильно перемешать колоду.

Comment: Реально случайные числа получить вам не удастся. Они всегда будут псевдослучайными.

Comment: Псевдослучайные все время одни и те же? Инициализируйте ГСЧ. А если текущие ГСЧ не устраивают - ищите другие варианты. Есть варианты ГСЧ, которые генерируют действительно случайные числа на основе шумов и/или используют какие-либо аппаратные привязки (напр., серийный номер процессора)

Comment: Да-да, подключите радиотелескоп и используйте галактический шум в качестве источника случайных чисел :)

Answer (score 2):

Как уже сказал [[@cy6erGn0m](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)
случайные числа получить нельзя. Но можно получить высококачественные псевдослучайные числа.
Как вариант почитайте про [Вихрь Мерсенна](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0)

или чтение /dev/random (/dev/urandom) с некоторым фильтром ...